# How to SELECT the top row per group based on multiple ordering columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a query that looks like the following:

```
SELECT time_start, some_count
    FROM foo
    WHERE user_id = 1
    AND DATE(time_start) = '2016-07-27'
    ORDER BY some_count DESC, time_start DESC LIMIT 1;
```

What this does is return me one row, where some_count is the highest count for `user_id = 1`. It also gives me the time stamp which is the most current for that `some_count`, as `some_count` could be the same for multiple `time_start` values and I want the most current one.

Now I'm trying to do is run a query that will figure this out for every single `user_id` that occurred at least once for a specific date, in this case `2016-07-27`. Ultimately it's going to probably require a GROUP BY as I'm looking for a group maximum per `user_id`

What's the best way to write a query of that nature?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT(user_id), ... will get you one entry per user without GROUP BY. What column do you want the MAX() value for?

Comment: I want the MAX() value for `some_count`, but I also need to know the MAX() `time_stop` for where that specific `some_count` matches as there could be multiple rows where `some_count` is the same for `user_id` and `time_stop`

Comment: What is the primary key?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel `id` which is an auto increment column.

Comment: can you please show initial table and final required table,so we can help you in better way

Comment: Is it always true : `time_start` column holds the maximum value where `some_count` holds the maximum (in the same row)? @randombits

Comment: @1000111the value `some_count` can occur the same on many rows, I need to get the row with the most recent `time_start` value, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sharing two of my approaches.

**Approach #1 (scalable):**

Using `MySQL user_defined variables`

```
SELECT
    t.user_id,
    t.time_start,
    t.time_stop,
    t.some_count
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        user_id,
        time_start,
        time_stop,
        some_count,
        IF(@sameUser = user_id, @rn := @rn + 1,
             IF(@sameUser := user_id, @rn := 1, @rn := 1)
        ) AS row_number

    FROM    foo
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT
            @sameUser := - 1,
            @rn := 1
    ) var
    WHERE   DATE(time_start) = '2016-07-27'
    ORDER BY    user_id,    some_count DESC,    time_stop DESC
) AS t
WHERE t.row_number <= 1
ORDER BY t.user_id;
```

Scalable because if you want latest n rows for each user then you just need to change this line :

`... WHERE t.row_number <= n...`

<sub>I can add explanation later if the query provides expected result</sub>

---

**Approach #2:(Not scalable)**

Using `INNER JOIN and GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
 F.user_id,
 F.some_count,
 F.time_start,
 MAX(F.time_stop) AS max_time_stop
FROM foo F
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        user_id,
        MAX(some_count) AS max_some_count
    FROM foo
    WHERE DATE(time_start) = '2016-07-27'
    GROUP BY user_id
) AS t
ON F.user_id = t.user_id AND F.some_count = t.max_some_count
WHERE DATE(time_start) = '2016-07-27'
GROUP BY F.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM foo t
WHERE (DATE(time_start) = '2016-07-27'
   OR DATE(time_stop) = '2016-07-27') 
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM foo s
                 WHERE t.user_id = s.user_id
                 AND (s.some_count > t.some_count
                  OR (s.some_count = t.some_count
                      AND s.time_stop > t.time_stop)))
```

The `NOT EXISTS()` will select only records that another record with a larger count or a another record with the same count but a newer `time_stop` doesn't exists for them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your original query as a correlated subquery in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT user_id, time_stop, some_count
FROM foo f
WHERE f.id = (
    SELECT f1.id
    FROM foo f1
    WHERE f1.user_id = f.user_id -- correlate
    AND DATE(f1.time_start) = '2016-07-27'
    ORDER BY f1.some_count DESC, f1.time_stop DESC LIMIT 1
)
```

MySQL should be able to cache the result of the subquery for every distinct `user_id`.

Another way is to use nested GROUP BY queries:

```
select f.user_id, f.some_count, max(f.time_stop) as time_stop
from (
    select f.user_id, max(f.some_count) as some_count
    from foo f
    where date(f.time_start) = '2016-07-27'
    group by f.user_id
) sub
join foo f using(user_id, some_count)
where date(f.time_start) = '2016-07-27'
group by f.user_id, f.some_count
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user_id,
       some_count,
       max(time_start) AS time_start
FROM
  (SELECT a.*
   FROM foo AS a
   INNER JOIN
     (SELECT user_id,
             max(some_count) AS some_count
      FROM foo
      WHERE DATE(time_start) = '2016-07-27'
      GROUP BY user_id) AS b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
   AND a.some_count = b.some_count) AS c
GROUP BY user_id,
         some_count;
```

Explaining from inside out: The most inner table (b) will give you the max some_count per user. this is not enough as you want the max for two columns - so I'm joining it with the full table (a) to get the records that has these max values (c), and from that I'm taking the max time_start for each user/some_count combination.

Comment: I had to edit my OP. I needed to `DESC` by `time_start`. The way your query runs now, I'm getting rows matching `time_start` not matching: `WHERE DATE(time_start) = '2016-07-27'`

Comment: @randombits - I edited my query, the change is to use `time_start` instead of `time_stop`. not sure I follow what you mean in your comment, you'll get entries from this day, but the max per day. what do you mean matching `time_start`?

Answer (score 1):

**Strategy**

In general it's more efficient to find maximum values rather than sorting groups of records. In this case, the ordering is on an integer (`some_count`) followed by a date/time (`time_start`) - so to find a single maximum row, we need to combine these in some way.

A simple way of doing this is to combine the two into a string but there is the usual snag of string comparison valuing `"4"` as higher than `"12"` for example. This is easily overcome by using [`LPAD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#idm139935329305744) to add leading zeros so `4` becomes `"0000000004"`, which is lower than `"0000000012"` in a string comparison. Assuming `time_start` is a `DATETIME` field, it can simply be appended to this for a secondary ordering since its string conversion results in a sortable format (`yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss`).

**SQL**

Using this strategy, we can restrict via a simple subselect:

```
SELECT time_start, some_count
FROM foo f1
WHERE DATE(time_start) = '2016-07-27'
  AND CONCAT(LPAD(some_count, 10, '0'), time_start) = 
      (SELECT MAX(CONCAT(LPAD(some_count, 10, '0'), time_start))
       FROM foo f2
       WHERE DATE(f2.time_start) = '2016-07-27'
         AND f2.user_id = f1.user_id);
```

**Demo**

Rextester demo here: http://rextester.com/HCGY1362

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you don't need to do anything fancy for the query.
Just sort the table by **user_id** in ascending order and **some_count** and **time_start**  in a descending order and select expected fields from the ordered table GROUP BY **user_id**. Its simple. Try and let me know if works.

```
SELECT user_id, some_count, time_start
FROM (SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY user_id ASC, some_count DESC, time_start DESC)sorted_foo
WHERE DATE( time_start ) = '2016-07-27'
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: There was a error in the previous answer. sorry for the unwanted mistake. I resolved the issues and checked. Seems now it working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be solved with something called **window functions**, but MySQL has no support for this kind of feature.

I have two solutions for you. One is simulating a window function and the other is the common way you'll write some queries to address these situations in MySQL.

This is the first one, which I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239626/retrieve-last-non-null-record-of-every-column-for-each-record-id-in-mysql/39240623#39240623):

```
-- simulates the window function
-- first_value(<col>) over(partition by user_id order by some_count DESC, time_start DESC)
SELECT
  user_id,
  substring_index(group_concat(time_start ORDER BY some_count DESC, time_start DESC), ',', 1) time_start,
  substring_index(group_concat(some_count ORDER BY some_count DESC, time_start DESC), ',', 1) some_count
FROM foo
WHERE DATE(time_start) = '2016-07-27'
GROUP BY user_id
;
```

Basically, you group your data by `user_id` and concatenates all values from a specified column using the `,` separator, ordered by the columns you want, for each group, and then substrings only the first ordered value. This is not an optimal approach...

And that's the second one, which I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302650/using-max-and-sum-for-the-same-column-without-subquery-mysql/39302868#39302868):

```
SELECT 
  user_id,
  some_count,
  MAX(time_start) time_start
FROM foo outq
WHERE 1=1
  AND DATE(time_start) = '2016-07-27'
  AND NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1
    FROM foo 
    WHERE 1=1
      AND user_id    = outq.user_id
      AND some_count > outq.some_count
      AND DATE(time_start) = DATE(outq.time_start)
  )
GROUP BY
  user_id,
  some_count
;
```

Basically, the subquery checks for each `user_id` if there are any `some_count` higher them the current one been checked on that date, as the main query expects it to `NOT EXISTS`. You'll left with all highest `some_count` per `user_id` in a date, but for a same highest value from a user may exists several different `time_start` in that date. Now things are simple. You can securely `GROUP BY` user and count, because they are already the data you want, and get from the group the maximum `time_start`.

This kind of subquery is the common way of solving problems like that in MySQL. I recommend you to try both solutions, but choose the second one and remember the subquery sintax to solve any future problem.

Also, in MySQL, an implicit `ORDER BY <columns>` is applied in all queries having a `GROUP BY <columns>`. If you don't bother with the result order, you can save some processing by declaring `ORDER BY NULL`, which will disable the implicit ordenation feature in your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  c1.user_id, c1.some_count, MAX(c1.time_start) AS time_start
    FROM  foo AS c1
    JOIN
      ( SELECT  user_id, MAX(some_count) AS some_count
            FROM  foo
            WHERE time_start >= '2016-07-27'
              AND time_start  < '2016-07-27' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
            GROUP BY  user_id
      ) AS c2 USING (user_id, some_count)
    GROUP BY c1.user_id, c1.some_count
```

And, add these for better performance:

```
INDEX(user_id, some_count, time_start)
INDEX(time_start)
```

The test for the `time_start` range was changed so that the second index could be used.

This was loosely derived from by blog on [*groupwise max*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) .