# Retrieve last non-null record of every column for each record_id in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this MySQL table named `records`. Below is its contents.

```
id  record_id   Data1   Data2   Time 
1   1           null    1       1/1/16
2   1           1       null    1/3/16
3   1           2       null    1/4/16
4   1           null    3       1/5/16
5   2           1       null    2/1/16
6   2           1       null    2/3/16
7   2           7       null    2/4/16
8   2           null    5       2/5/16
```

I would like to have a MySQL query to retrieve the last non-null record of each column for each `record_id`. The result would look something like;

```
record_id   Data1   Data2   Time 
1           2       3       1/5/16
2           7       5       2/5/16
```

The tricky part to this problem is that multiple columns are involved.

Comment: Those results look completely arbitrary. Also why are your `id` values being duplicated? That schema is mind-bendingly confusing. I also hope your dates aren't in `DD/MM/YY` format. Did Y2K teach us nothing? Use `YYYY-MM-DD`, the ISO-8601 standard.

Comment: Sorry. id is the primary key. It should be unique.

Comment: That's a lot more sane. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @tadman Just noticed this after posting what I think the OP wants.

Comment: It's a max by grouping. It has been asked many times. Please search better in the future

Comment: @Drew It turns out we were both wrong.  See below for some really ugly queries, courtesy of MySQL not having any analytical functions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how is this wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one may solve your problem:

```
select 
  record_id,
  substring_index(group_concat(Data1 order by Time desc), ',', 1) Data1,
  substring_index(group_concat(Data2 order by Time desc), ',', 1) Data2,
  substring_index(group_concat(Time  order by Time desc), ',', 1) Time
from records
group by record_id
;
```

It may not be as fast as other answers, but is another version... give it a try. If you have a `Data3` column in your table, you can copy/paste the `Data1` column and just change all references of this column to the new one.

Just to explain how this works: the `group_concat` function concatenates all non-null values of a column with a separator (`,` by default). You can order the column before the concatenation. It works a bit like a window function in Oracle, Postgre, and others... The `substring_index` is just getting the first concatenated value, as the list is in a descending order of time.

Comment: Just a downside in my own answer... as it's concatenating all values from a column, its type changes to some text type, maybe varchar... you may need to convert the type back to the original one at some point...

Comment: Neatest answer among all the answers. Brilliant! The best thing is that it is easy to add additional columns without adding too much code. I don't quite understand the downside that you mentioned. I will be displaying the output in a Web API in json which will all be in text. So, if the type changes to some text type, it shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: Yeah, in your case the type convertion is unnecessary. You should consider an index creation to speed things up, maybe composite on `record_id, Time DESC`. Also, setting the max size of `group_concat` concatenation may help. Put a low value, higher them your larger data length. You should set it just in the current session or just before the query, setting it back to your expected value after, so you'll not break anyone else `group_concat` code.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT record_id, MAX(Time) AS Time
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY record_id
) t2
    ON t1.record_id = t2.record_id AND
       t1.Time = t2.Time
```

If you simply want the *greatest* value for the data and time columns, then see the answer given by @Matt.  But your language makes it unclear what you really want.

**Update:**

Something like this might give the results you want:

```
SELECT a.record_id,
       a.Data1,
       b.Data2,
       c.Time
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.record_id,
           t1.Data1
    FROM yourTable t1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT record_id,
               MAX(CASE WHEN Data1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE id END) AS Data1Id
        FROM yourTable
        GROUP BY record_id
    ) t2
        ON t1.record_id = t2.record_id AND
           t1.Id = t2.Data1Id
) a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.record_id,
           t1.Data2
    FROM yourTable t1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT record_id,
               MAX(CASE WHEN Data2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE id END) AS Data2Id
        FROM yourTable
        GROUP BY record_id
    ) t2
        ON t1.record_id = t2.record_id AND
           t1.Id = t2.Data2Id
) b
    ON a.record_id = b.record_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.record_id,
           t1.Time
    FROM yourTable t1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT record_id,
               MAX(CASE WHEN Data2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE id END) AS TimeId
        FROM yourTable
        GROUP BY record_id
    ) t2
        ON t1.record_id = t2.record_id AND
           t1.Id = t2.TimeId
) c
    ON a.record_id = c.record_id
```

## Demo Here:

## SQLFiddle

Comment: How the hell did you come out with the answer so fast when I was stuck for so long? Are you a genius? Let me try out your answer.

Comment: this gives results 4,1,NULL,3,1/5/2016 and 8,2,NULL,5,2/5/2016  that doesn't look like the results desired in OP.

Comment: My question was badly phrased. I have corrected accordingly. Thanks, Matt. You are sharp! I tried out the answer and the output was not what I wanted.

Comment: @LitAiy I updated my answer again, please have a look, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are just wanting the maximum data1, max data2, and max time which would be simple aggregation:

```
SELECT
  record_id
  ,MAX(Data1) as Data1
  ,MAX(Data2) as Data2
  ,MAX(Time) as Time
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  record_id
```

SQL fiddle for it http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d95bc1/2

If latest non-null value per column is desired you can use:

```
SELECT t.record_id, MAX(t.Data1) as Data1, MAX(t.Data2) as Data2, MAX(t.Time) as Time
FROM
  yourTable t
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      record_id, MAX(Time) as MaxTime
    FROM
      yourTable t
    WHERE
      Data1 IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
      record_id
  ) d1
  ON t.record_id = d1.record_id
  AND t.Time = d1.MaxTime
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      record_id, MAX(Time) as MaxTime
    FROM
      yourTable t
    WHERE
      Data2 IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
      record_id  
   ) d2
  ON t.record_id = d2.record_id
  AND t.Time = d2.MaxTime
WHERE
  d1.record_id IS NOT NULL
  OR d2.record_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  t.record_id
```

Using Tim's method you can actually still get to your results looking at the Latest Data1 record and then the latest Data2 record and then aggregating so they are not purely the MAX of everything but rather representative of the latest 2 records 1 for Data1 and 1 for Data2.

SQL fiddle for this part: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d95bc1/10

Comment: `retrieve the latest record` ... the adjective "latest" really only makes sense when used with a date or time column.  Hence, my interpretation is that the OP wants the latest record for each group.  You might be right, but this isn't very clear.

Comment: Creating a query which gives verbatim what a question says isn't always the best thing to do.

Comment: You are right. The question was poorly phrased. The question should use the word last, and not latest. Corrected accordingly.

Comment: @LitAiy No, the question should use the word `max` or `greatest`, and specify which columns you want in the result set.

Comment: I am with Tim, I guess we are not clear (or just me :) ) on what it is you want.  Tim's method is great and I have seem lots of brilliant answers from him I just saw a discrepancy and wasn't sure what you wanted.  I did update my answer you can still tweak Tim's if you are looking for the 2 latest records and there are ways to do this variables to create row numbers too but at last I am better at sql-sever so I don't always tackle the latter

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, max or greatest is not what I want. The desired value is the latest non-null value in the column. Sorry, my fault for not being clear.

Comment: The that you are actually looking for 2 latest non-null values 1 for Data 1 and 1 for Data 2 is that correct?  see my most recent edit

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to have a MySQL query to retrieve the last non-null record of each column for each `record_id`.

Of course, what is still somewhat unclear is how you determine that a row is the *last* row, since rows in a database are by definition unordered.

So, my interpretation is that you want the *last* non-null `Data1`, `Data2` and `Time` column values for each distinct `record_id` value.  And a row value is considered *last* if it has a higher `id` value than another row value.

Assuming my understanding is correct, the following query would work:

```
select t.record_id,
       (select t2.Data1 
          from tbl t2 
         where t2.record_id = t.record_id 
           and t2.Data1 is not null
          order by t2.id desc
          limit 1) as Data1,
       (select t2.Data2
          from tbl t2 
         where t2.record_id = t.record_id 
           and t2.Data2 is not null
          order by t2.id desc
          limit 1) as Data2,
       (select t2.Time
          from tbl t2 
         where t2.record_id = t.record_id 
           and t2.Time is not null
          order by t2.id desc
          limit 1) as Time
  from tbl t
group by t.record_id
order by t.record_id
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48d8ba/1)