# Pyspark: last non null record for each id in dataframe (Spark Streaming)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with schema -

```
 |-- record_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Data1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Data2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Data3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Time: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

I wanted to retrieve the last non null value for each column in the data, grouping by the record_id and sorted by the time.If all value for the column (for that particular record_is) is null, I want null to be displayed in that case.

So,if the data is initially this:

```
 +----------+---------+---------+---------+-----------------------+
 |record_id |Data1    |Data2    |Data3    |                   Time|
 +----------+---------+-------------------------------------------+
 |        1 | aaa     | null    |  null   | 2018-06-04 21:51:53.0 |
 |        1 | null    | bbbb    |  cccc   | 2018-06-05 21:51:53.0 |
 |        1 | aaa     | null    |  dddd   | 2018-06-06 21:51:53.0 |
 |        1 | null    | null    |  eeee   | 2018-06-07 21:51:53.0 |
 |        2 | aaa     | null    |  null   | 2018-06-04 21:51:53.0 |
 |        2 | null    | bbbb    |  cccc   | 2018-06-05 21:51:53.0 |
 |        3 | aaa     | null    |  dddd   | 2018-06-06 21:51:53.0 |
 |        3 | null    | null    |  eeee   | 2018-06-08 21:51:53.0 |
```

I want the output to be

```
 +----------+---------+---------+---------+-----------------------+
 |record_id |Data1    |Data2    |Data3    |                   Time|
 +----------+---------+-------------------------------------------+
 |        1 | aaaa    | bbbb    |  eeee   | 2018-06-07 21:51:53.0 |
 |        2 | aaaa    | bbbb    |  cccc   | 2018-06-05 21:51:53.0 |
 |        3 | aaaa    | null    |  eeee   | 2018-06-08 21:51:53.0 |
```

I wanted to do this in Pyspark, using Spark SQL. The closest answer I could get, is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239626/retrieve-last-non-null-record-of-every-column-for-each-record-id-in-mysql), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43876822/pyspark-get-first-non-null-value-of-each-column-in-dataframe) though the first is in mysql, while the second does not group the records.