# Using Max and Sum for the same column without subquery -Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to Mysql,I wanted to use both sum(Max(column)) ?

I don't know why its impossible to use?

whereas count(Distinct(column)) is possible i.e using two aggregate functions together

Comment: have you tried anything? show us the code

Comment: @ZaidMirza ya i tried ,it wont work even with basic queries ,Only solution is subqueries

Comment: Distinct is not a function (aggregating or otherwise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is SUM() and MAX() both are aggregate functions and these functions returning results by grouping their inputs across the table . While applying one aggregate function over another, it is something like grouping data over the result set of another grouping function and that is not allowed in SQL.

But in SQL Server, from 2008 version onwards introduced a new clause OVER() so that we can specify the grouping criteria in that over clause for that particular column.

In the case of DISTINCT which does not need any grouping and it pull the distinct record set over which we are applying the aggregate function. So that will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform in the following way but if you are not using orther grouping columns then it always return 1 column so SUM(MAX(tot)) = MAX(tot) though we are not allow to do it in same place:

```
SELECT SUM(total) tot FROM (
SELECT 
    MAX(quantity) total 
    FROM deliveries) t;
```

Comment: @S Bohara but i am asking the reason why its not supported,I am good with the alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` is not an aggregate function. It's a keyword, a basic command.

In your case, when you're getting the `MAX` from a group you're getting a single value. `SUM` a single value makes no sense.

If you want so `SUM` the `MAX` values from all existing groups, you could try like this:

```
SELECT SUM(<column>)
FROM <table> t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
    -- filter all max values from each group
    SELECT 1
    FROM <table> d
    WHERE 1=1
      AND d.<group_column1> = t.<group_column1>
      AND d.<group_column2> = t.<group_column2>
      ... 
      AND d.<column> > t.<column>
  )
```

Comment: I can get more values while using Max and group by function select max(column_name ) from table group by column2 //For each group it will find the maximum and give us

Comment: So those values i need to sum

Comment: why is there a `WHERE 1=1` in your query? What is it for?

Comment: While developing the SQL I comment out a lot of `WHERE` filters and while commenting out the first/last filter I don't want the "extra work" of removing its next/previous `AND` operator.